# Swift 2 : iOS 8+ How to store latitude/longitude with CoreLocation and stop locating

Tags: ios, swift2

Yeah ! My CoreLocation working now ! So i have a problem to store latitude and longitude and stopping locating.

I have a Sign In page (my MainVC)

before user sign in i need to get and store current device location and stop locating (now it's working with help of Alexander see under).

in my MainVC.swift i have this 2 global variables

```
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocations = [CLLocation]()
```

in my viewDidLoad() i have this :

```
        //Setup our Location Manager
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

For operate locationManager i have this 2 functions :

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("locations = \(locations)")
    errorMsgIfInternetNotAvailable.text = "GPS success"

    myLocations.append(locations.last!)

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    errorMsgIfInternetNotAvailable.text = "Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription
}
```

When i build my app, all working, if not autorise my device to get GPS informations i have the locationManager function error working.

If i autorise it

in console, the location update every second and don't stop it with the .stopUpdatingLocation() command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is always good to provide the build error output. It's hard enough to guess which error you're getting.

It seems like you defined, but not initialized `myLocations` property. You have to do it like this:

```
var myLocations = [CLLocation]()
```

Notice the brackets `()` in initialization.

And then you have to *add* object to your array:

```
myLocations.append(locations.last)
```

or, if you want to store only one object in your array, do it like:

```
myLocations = [locations.last]
```

Comment: I change myLocations init so i can't use myLocations[0] = locations.last! :(

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525 You're trying to add object to not initialized array. You have defined it, but have not initialized.

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525 I've updated my answer because i've found one more error in your code. Try it again.

Comment: Great it's working with .append(locations.last!) and I have access to latitude and longitude so my app not stop to locating every second

Comment: That would be great if you post new question for new problem, leaving this one for another people who have the same question.

Comment: Do you have an idea to stopping location ??

Comment: Thank you so much Alex ! now everyting is working i just change the .stopUpdatingLocation in my viewDidLoad() and ad your 2 lines after !

Comment: You have to unset location manager delegate. Write `locationManager.delegate = nil` after `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`.